# Detect touch and hold with UITableViewCell, what are my options?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

With my current table view controller, I'd like to implement a touch and hold feature very similar to how the click-wheel iPod's On-The-Go queueing feature used to work.

I've been reading a few posts and have seen suggestions for using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. Whilst I could do that, it does bring up a couple more questions for me:

1. If a long press is detected, how can I prevent the
   `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method from being called (Or do I
   completely avoid using it and implement a Tap gesture recogniser in
   my UITableViewCell subclass?)
2. How would I go about animating the cell once a long-press has been
   detected similar to the iPod style (where the highlighted cell
   flashes/opacity of highlight goes up and down a few times).

Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the long press recognizer, and it fires, didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not fire.

You can detect the state of the gesture recognizer and animate your cell after the 'start' state is detected, and end the animation when the 'end' state is detected.

if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) ...
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) ...

Comment: Is there a way I can disable scrolling from Began to Ended?

Comment: I believe that's the default behavior. Try it out and let us know! If not, implement the gesture recognizer delegate method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` to return NO, and it will block the scroll view's gesture recognizers.